# How to decrypt data after scan through QR code Scanner for RSA

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, qr-code, digital-signature

I have already encrypt my data and generate QR code to store it. But,when I scan the QR code through QR scanner, it just scan the encrypted message and not decrypt the message back. Can someone guide to solve this issue.

This is my code for encrypt decrypt

```java
public class SecureQRcodeWithDigitalSignature {

    private PrivateKey privateKey;
    private PublicKey publicKey;
public SecureQRcodeWithDigitalSignature () {
        
        
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            generator.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
            privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
            publicKey = pair.getPublic();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String message) throws Exception{
        byte[] messageToBytes = message.getBytes();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(messageToBytes);
        return encode(encryptedBytes);
    }
    private String encode(byte[] data){
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) throws Exception{
        byte[] encryptedBytes = decode(encryptedMessage);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        return new String(decryptedMessage,"UTF8");
    }
    private byte[] decode(String data){
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner message = new Scanner(System.in);
       
        String data= message.nextLine();
        
       SecureQRcodeWithDigitalSignature  rsa = new SecureQRcodeWithDigitalSignature ();
        try{
            String encryptedMessage = rsa.encrypt(data);
            String decryptedMessage = rsa.decrypt(encryptedMessage);

           System.err.println("Encrypted:\n"+encryptedMessage);
            System.err.println("Decrypted:\n"+decryptedMessage);
        }catch (Exception ignored){}`
```

This is my code for scanner

```java
    public void run (){
     do {
         try {
             Thread.sleep(100);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ScannerQR.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
     Result result = null;
     BufferedImage image = null;
     
     String data = result_field.getText();
     if(webcam.isOpen()){
         if((image = webcam.getImage()) ==null){
         continue;
     }}
        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap (new HybridBinarizer(source));
      
        
         try {
             result= new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
             
         } catch (NotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ScannerQR.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      if (result != null){
          
          SecureQRcodeWithDigitalSignature  b = new SecureQRcodeWithDigitalSignature ();
          
            result_field.setText(result.getText());
            result_field.setEditable(false);
            
         plaintext_result.setText(data);
      }
        
     }while(true);
     }
```

Comment: Hi Hanis, did you manage to decrypt your QR code?